# web-gui without web-server

Tags: perl, user-interface, module, administration

Does somebody know a module which allows me to write a web-gui for my script (like the  web-administration-tools from cups and samba) without installing/configuring/running a web-server analog to the DBD::SQLite where I can use a database without the need of a database-server.

Answer (score 2):

Install module Plack then run your webserver

```
plackup --listen localhost:80 --loader Shotgun -MPlack::App::WrapCGI -e " Plack::App::WrapCGI->new( script => q{test.cgi} ) "

HTTP::Server::PSGI: Accepting connections at http://localhost:80/
```

test.cgi is written the standard way (same as you would for apache cgi-bin)
Shotgun means test.cgi will be reloaded each time you edit test.cgi

Answer (score 2):

Use some microwebframework like [`Dancer`](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [`Mojolicious`](http://www.mojolicious.org/)

Dancer example (including simple webserver):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Dancer;

get '/hello/:name' => sub {
        return "Why, hello there " . params->{name};
};

dance;
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a Plack application. Bundle it with one of the supported stand-alone servers, e.g. HTTP::Server::Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to <strike>embed a webserver (or something that at least understood basic HTTP) into</strike> add code to your application that listened on a TCP port and serviced basic HTTP requests.

A quick google found this article/tutorial that should get you started:

http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/09/17/ewispp.html

(Edited in an attempt to avoid confusion around "embedding a webserver")

Comment: But you would have to run it in order to make it work and he mentioned `without installing/configuring/running a web-server` or am I missing something and what he means is that he wants to make HIS own webserver that does not rely on apache or IIS or any other.

Comment: *facepalm* - if you want to **serve** content for the **web** (i.e. via HTTP) then you need... wait for it... A WEB SERVER. The whole "without installing/configuring" part is the OP asking for an embedded web server.

Comment: Run what? You just add code to your perl script to listen on a TCP port and service HTTP requests - maybe "embed a webserver" is a little strong, but that's basically what you're doing. But yeah - he wants to add a web GUI to his script without having to have a full-on webserver setup.  See the link I posted :)

Comment: I understand what you mean and your answer, I am just confused about the OP question. I mean with what you posted you would have to start the perl so it would bind to the port and start working, in a way you still need to run it if that is what the OP meant, in the other hand if what he meant was just about apache, IIS and the suchs this would fit perfectly.